# JQuery - display multiple text input values and corresponding hidden input values on keyup

Tags: jquery, forms

So there is 4 inputs (example only, in reality more and generated from mysql), if I fill the value in with the use of keyup function the values being automaticaly displayed. I'm very new to jQuery and need to find the way to display corresponding name and the price of the item that are stored in hidden input of the form. (pack01-name and pack01-price and so on}

```
<div class="content" id="packcontent_01" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="content" id="packcontent_02" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="content" id="packcontent_03" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="content" id="packcontent_04" style="display: none;"></div>

<p>Pack 1</p>
<input type="text" class="pack" name="pack01"  id="pack01" autocomplete="off" maxlength="2" value="" />
<input type="hidden" class="pack" id="pack01-name" name="pack01-name" value="Name of Pack 1" />
<input type="hidden" class="pack" id="pack01-price" name="pack01-price" value="5.00" />
<p>Pack 2</p>
<input type="text" class="pack" name="pack02" value="" id="pack02" autocomplete="off" maxlength="2"  />
<input type="hidden" class="pack" id="pack02-name" name="pack02-name" value="Name of Pack 2" />
<input type="hidden" class="pack" id="pack02-price" name="pack02-price" value="6.00" />
<p>Pack 3</p>
<input type="text" class="pack" name="pack03" value="" id="pack03" autocomplete="off" maxlength="2"  />
<input type="hidden" class="pack" id="pack03-name" name="pack03-name" value="Name of Pack 3" />
<input type="hidden" class="pack" id="pack03-price" name="pack03-price" value="7.00" />
<p>Pack 4</p>
<input type="text" class="pack" name="pack04" value="" id="pack04" autocomplete="off" maxlength="2"  />
<input type="hidden" class="pack" id="pack04-name" name="pack04-name" value="Name of Pack 4" />
<input type="hidden" class="pack" id="pack04-price" name="pack04-price" value="8.00" />

<script>
$(".pack").keyup(function() {
var curId = this.id.split("k")[1];
$("#packcontent_"+curId).html($(this).val());
$("#packcontent_"+curId).show();
});
</script>
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/nitadesign/pvw017uw/

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Will `$('#pack'+curId+'-name').val()` get you the behavior you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know what kind of display you want, just update this code.

```
   $(".pack").keyup(function () {
        var curId = this.id.split("k")[1];
        var packName = $('#pack' + curId + '-name').val();
        var packPrice = $('#pack' + curId + '-price').val();
        $("#packcontent_" + curId).html($(this).val() + ', Name :  ' + packName + ', Price : ' + packPrice);
        $("#packcontent_" + curId).show();
    });
```

Updated :

```
 $(".pack").keyup(function () {
        var curId = this.id.split("k")[1];
        var packName = $('#pack' + curId + '-name').val();
        var packPrice = $('#pack' + curId + '-price').val();

        if ($(this).val() == '') {
             $("#packcontent_" + curId).hide();
        }
        else {
            $("#packcontent_" + curId).html($(this).val() + ', Name :  ' + packName + ', Price : ' + packPrice);
            $("#packcontent_" + curId).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Great, thank you. Now I can display corresponding information. There is one problem. Before when I put the value in - value was displayed, when I cleared the input value disappeared. So that is fine. But now once additional information are displayed once, the stay and I would like them to disappear too, if corresponding input value has been cleared. Any suggestions ?? Please take a look at updated fiddle.

Comment: @Nita tell me if this is what u want, cant understand clearly what u want.
:)

Comment: Dont forget to upvote or mark as answer if it helps, glad to help

Comment: this is perfect, Thanks for your help. Also thanks for up vote tip. I do not have enough reputation yet to have them visible!

Comment: @Nita you can just click the upvote  and the check under it.

Comment: Done. Thank you for your Help.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your JQuery with

```
$(".pack").keyup(function () {
    var curId = this.id.split("k")[1];     
    $("#packcontent_" + curId).html($("#pack"+curId+"-name").val()+" -- "+$("#pack"+curId+"-price").val());
    $("#packcontent_" + curId).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".pack").keyup(function () {
    var curId = this.id.split("k")[1];
    var packName = $('#pack' + curId + '-name').val();
    var packPrice = $('#pack' + curId + '-price').val();

    if ($(this).val() == '') {
         $("#packcontent_" + curId).hide();
    }
    else {
        $("#packcontent_" + curId).html($(this).val() + ', Name :  ' + packName + ', Price : ' + packPrice);
        $("#packcontent_" + curId).show();
    }
});
```